# Can't mount replacement hdd to same spot?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I replaced my media hdd with a larger size and now I cant mount it to the same location as the old one /mnt/ultron

I have deleted the ultron directory and recreated it, I have tried using the disks application, I even tried modifying /etc/fstab to have the new hdd's uuid. It appears to unmount instantly when I try mounting it.

I have successfully mounted it to other spots such as /mnt/ultrons just to test, but it will not mount to /mnt/ultron

My current /etc/fstab was created with disks and I have verified the uuid is correct. It even works if I change the mount point to anything else.

Here is my fstab

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=F1D3-05E0 
/boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a815ea68-9d8c-41fa-9534-cabb080013c0 /mnt/ultron auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: It should be as easy as editing the new GUID in fstab. But if you already deleted the old entry then it should just work with any of the available methods.

Comment: Please always edit the question to add relevant information, not just comments. Now, how could I know if it "looks right"? I can see it has a mount point /mnt/ultron but ehther or not its ID corresponds to the new or the old, nobody else but you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for anyone facing this in the future. Simply run this command in terminal:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

The answer and explanation is here.
https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/480-disk-automatically-unmounts-immediately-after-mounting